# Float in center of browser?

Tags: jquery, html, tumblr

I wrote some jquery (apologise for the syntax) which centers a div in the middle of the browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function move_div(){
        window_width =      $(window).width();
        window_height =     $(window).height();

        obj_width =         $('#div_to_center').width();
        obj_height =        $('#div_to_center').height();

        $('#div_to_center').css('top', (window_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2)).css('left', (window_width / 2) - (obj_width / 2));

    }

    move_div();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        move_div();
    });

});
```

What I want to do is implement this into Tumblr so a div like [this](http://speakingwithpictures.com/post/56862947287) is centered.

However, I'm not to familiar with Tumblr's API. And how I go about implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should add `.css('position', 'fixed')`

but you can just use pure CSS:

this will put your box in center of the page :

```
#box{
    width: width;
    height: height;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -width/2;       
    margin-top: -height/2;       
}
```

Comment: +1 for useful input. The question title is "Float in center of browser?", the text asks for Tumblrs JavaScript API, so it seems to be a legitimate answer to the question even if it does not follow the path Michael is currently going.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#div {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
#content {
margin: auto;
}
```